# In Nodejs Express App Route is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-router

I have an app.js file as -

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const userRoute = require('./routes/user.route');
app.use('/user', userRoute);

app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(chalk.blue(`Express app listening at http://localhost:${port}`));
});
```

My route file is -

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const userController = require('../controllers/user.controller');

router.post('/:id', userController.userDetails);
router.post('/toggleActive', userController.toggleStatus);

module.exports = router;
```

I am unable to reach '/toggleActive' path.

But if i define route file as -

```
router.post('/toggleActive', userController.toggleStatus);
router.post('/:id', userController.userDetails);

module.exports = router;
```

Then everything is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define routes like this

```
router.post('/:id', userController.userDetails);
router.post('/toggleActive', userController.toggleStatus);
```

then server will catch everything that is sent with POST to `/user` because `:id` is a variable. It might as well be a string "toggleActive".
You can do something like this

```
router.post('/:id/toggleActive', userController.toggleStatus);
router.post('/:id', userController.userDetails);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your url

```
/user/toogleActive
```

will be matched by the route with the path.  Meaning the first route defined will be matched by the url which will extract toogleActive as a param. However to change this,  route

```
/toogleActive
```

should  be placed before as a to achieve the first matching policy used by express.